# Reporting Services: empty pages on report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Please note that I am aware of the "blank page issue" reported and solved so many times on all forums.
The issue there was that fields grow or overlap the page margins, causing Reporting Services to add pages (that in turn are not used).
This is NOT my problem. I took careful note of page margins, field size and CanGrow settings!

My problem is that the report, rendered with my Visual Studio environment or rendered by me surfing to server/reports works absolutly fine, but when called through subscription produces empty pages.
In both case I use default values for parameters.

The report consists of a cover sheet and 3 or 4 data pages for each year reported (depending on customer used) and every page looks exactly as expected when opened manually. No white pages where should be data, no additional white generated - perfect.

I can save this preview to PDF, from VS or the website, and both PDFs are generated perfect.

When I subscribe the report, either using "Drop File in Fileshare" or using "Email it" only the cover sheet is rendered (feeding back input parameters to me) but the detail pages are blank.

The detail pages are correct in number, 3 or 4 again, fitting exactly the expectation for the customer reported on. They are just completly blank.

What I did:

* Changed Data Source on server to use given credentials

* Rendered in VS or website manually, save PDF or XLS: Perfect result.

* Rendered through subscription to PDF, XLS or MHTML: Blank pages (File Share or Email option)

* Inspect Report Server Log files: No errors reported, about 15 log lines generated per subscription

* Inspect SQL Profiler on database: No errors, queries as expected, data access looks fine

I am out of ideas at this point.

The report does use subreports, the whole missing pages are all contained in a subreport (having subreports in it again). I am not sure if this is part of the problem.
The cover page that is displayed is on the highest order, it is the report called. The first order of subreports does contain a picture and subreports (but no textboxes, neither fixed or data filled). Anyway, that header picture of subreport 1 should be appearing at least?

But, as said, Visual Studio and the reporting webpage do work fine...

System: SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer, build 10.50.4033 (SP2 I think this is) running on Windows Server 2008 R2. More version details (if needed) can be supplied.
I think there is no execution account set for reporting services - I am not sure if I need it as the report itself calls up fine, and data access credentials are supplied in the data source.

*edit: I added page header and footer to the main report (configured to not display on first page) and they DO show on all detail pages now.
The data area in these detail pages still is completly empty when subscribed, and perfectly fine when opened manually.

The data area in question is the a subreport inside a tablix that iterates "years with the customer".
There was a known issue in SQL Reporting Services 2005 with Excel not being able to render subreports embedded in data iterator regions.

That describes exactly what I am getting as error, but nothing else matches the circumstances (SQL 2008 R2, export to PDF/MHTML/XLS, ONLY when subscribed)

Comment: If only all questions could have that level of detail

Comment: Are you displaying the parameters on the report? If no, can you add them and see if the report generated with the subscription displays the correct parameters? That way we could close the door of wrong parameters.

Comment: I put parameter-textboxes on the main report, and they come out fine. I added textboxes to the subreport, but the pages still stay blank.

Comment: Good to hear you've found a solution or acceptable workaround. Please post it as an answer with some details so it's easier for others with similar issues to spot.

Comment: @Jeroen - I don't think his issue was resolved

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Hmm, the latest edit started with OP stating "Problem solved now". I rolled back that edit, because answers should be posted as such (I'm sure there's some meta threads backing this up, can't quickly find one atm). My last comment was to ping OP about this, though I forgot to mention / link to [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30392357/revisions) to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this issue, but at least figure out an acceptable workaround.

The original idea was to reduce complexity of reports and queries by having many small subreports, and stacking them deep into each other. Each subreport then contains one or two dataset at most, with very basic SQL.
This layout would have required the main report and 3 levels of subreports.

I now pulled up all in just one subreport (so it is now main report and subreport). The issue discussed before does not appear anymore.